# @Autowired @Service Bean is null although set up properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

I get this error during start of my Spring Boot 2.1.4 based application:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [test.services.AlmConnectivity]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:184) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1295) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at test.services.AlmConnectivity.initProxyBean(AlmConnectivity.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at test.services.AlmConnectivity.<init>(AlmConnectivity.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
```

The mentioned line `43` is the one that starts with `proxy =`:

```
@DependsOn({ "config", "cfg" })
private void initProxyBean() {
    System.err.println("Config: " + config);
    proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(config.getProxyHost(), config.getProxyPort()));
}
```

`System.err` prints null too. As you can see I tried to signal dependencies using `@DependsOn`.

These are the (I guess) other relevant parts of the class:

```
@Service
public class AlmConnectivity {
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AlmConnectivity.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("config")
    Config config;

    private Proxy proxy;

    private OkHttpClient client;

    public AlmConnectivity() {
        initProxyBean();
        initClientBean(proxy);
    }
```

Because I prefer shorter names I used `@Qualifier`, but even if I skip this and take the bean with its full name `config` it doesn't work and config stays null.

This is the config class:

```
@Component
public class Config {

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Value("${proxy.host}")
    private String proxyHost = "i.am.desparate";

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Value("${proxy.port}")
    private int proxyPort = 8090;

    public String getProxyHost() {
        return proxyHost;
    }

    public int getProxyPort() {
        return proxyPort;
    }
}
```

My main class carries these annotations:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
```

(The latter three were added during my attempts to get this running)

Comment: Hope, you might followd the basics. Could you share the bean definiton part of "cfg".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to change your behaviour from being called in the constructor to a

```
javax.annotation.PostConstruct
```

annotated method:

```
@Service
public class AlmConnectivity {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AlmConnectivity.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("config")
    Config config;

    private Proxy proxy;

    private OkHttpClient client;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initProxyBean() {
        System.err.println("Config: " + config);
        proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(config.getProxyHost(), config.getProxyPort()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem. I knew Spring will provide a solution to this ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add an information on the answer provided above by Smutje:

Bean constructors are meant to create instances of the bean.

Spring first calls the Bean constructor, and only after that, when there is an instance of the bean, calls Autowiring logic (You can read about bean post processors in Spring to understand exactly how they work, its out of scope for this question, though).

After the Autowiring logic is done and all the autowired fields are injected, Spring calls method annotated with `@PostConstruct`.

This is the place where you can initialize your code.

So one of the possible answers is indeed using the bean post constructor.

Another way is to stop using Field Injection in favor of Constructor Injection:

```
@Service  
public class AlmConnectivity {

  @Autowired // optional annotation in modern spring if you have a single constructor
  public AlmConnectivity(@Qualifier("config") Config  config) {
       // here config is not null, so you can init proxy
  }
}
```